# Why wordpress get_post_meta not returning anything, when my DB has value?

Tags: wordpress

[database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBUjt.png)

```
return array( get_post_meta(12785, 'attribute_settings', true));
```

or

```
return array( get_post_meta("12785", 'attribute_settings', true));
```

it returns [""]
changing the key with another value, it returns the value in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that if you change the key, you get the value you want. Looking at your screenshot, you've got **duplicate keys** for `attribute_settings`. *How* you got a duplicate key in there, I'm not sure (did you add them directly in phpMyAdmin? Using [`update_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta) will update the record if it exists)

Now, I haven't seen the case before where a duplicate `post_id:meta_key` pair exists, but I'd wager it's returning at the `NULL` value since it's first. Delete that entry and you should be good.

[image: Picture of the duplicate]

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `update_post_meta()` | [Updates a post meta field based on the given post ID.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta) |

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
$attribute_settings = array();

$attribute_settings[] = get_post_meta( 12785, 'attribute_settings', true );

return $attribute_settings;
```